# how to find someone's Careers 2.0 profile based on their SO info

Tags: support, jobs

let's say I know someones StackOverflow name or user ID. is there any way for me to find their Careers 2.0 profile? I mean from just that info. assume they're not actively promoting their SO name on their careers profile or anything.

Answer (score 4):

Originally the decision was not to force any such connection.  If someone wanted their career's link in their profile they could easily add it.

You'd probably have an uphill battle convincing everyone that such a link should be required on stackoverflow profiles.